# WebAPI: custom parameter mapping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Given the controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyResponse Get([FromUri] MyRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And the model:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public Coordinate Point { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Coordinate
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
}
```

And the API url:

```
/api/my?Point=50.71,4.52
```

I'd like the `Point` property of the type `Coordinate` to be converted from the querystring value `50.71,4.52` before reaching the controller.

Where can I hook in to the WebAPI to make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a similar thing with a model binder.
See option #3 of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx).

Your model binder would be something like this:

```
public class MyRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext,
                          ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var key = "Point";
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (val != null) {
            var s = val.AttemptedValue as string;
            if (s != null) {
                var points = s.Split(',');
                bindingContext.Model = new Models.MyRequest {
                    Point = new Models.Coordinate {
                        X = Convert.ToDecimal(points[0],
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Y = Convert.ToDecimal(points[1],
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    }
                };
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You must then wire it up into the model binding system in the action:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public MyRequest Get([FromUri(BinderType=typeof(MyRequestModelBinder))] MyRequest request)
    {
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with that it that I'll have to bind every single property manually. Let's say that the model also has a `int Radius` property, I'd like that to bind automatically. Would that be possible?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, you have to bind everything. After all, you are telling the system how to transform the querystring into an instance of a type. I imagine you could add some reflection hocus pocus to parse the rest, but that I haven't done in this context.

Comment: It is possible to only bind a certain type of property, more details: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Hi David, just seeing this question and I have been working on something similar. To answer your most recent question, yes you can just bind some of the properties in the request and ignore the others. In the example here https://www.codingcurve.com/snippet/616/how-to-convert-custom-parameters-to-a-model-in-asp-net-web-api-2/ the request binds both the u & t parameters, but ignore the otherData parameter. The otherData parameter is still correctly bound to the parameter in the request, but ignoref from the custom model binder